# Best practice to stack html elements inside a div

Tags: javascript, html

I've been developing web pages for some time now and always had to use divs and floats in order to build pages.

I've been wondering what's the best practice for the next issue:

```
------------------------<div>-------------------------
|                                                    |
| <div w float left>              <div w float right>|
|                                                    |
------------------------------------------------------
```

or

```
------------------------<div>-------------------------
|                                                    |
| <span>                                       <span>|
|                                                    |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I simply won't two elements inside a div element, should they be spans or divs ?

The two elements inside the div will just hold texts and one of them will be a clickable element

Comment: Please find the difference between [`div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) and [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span).

Comment: By default a `div` is a `block-level element` whereas a `span` is an `inline`element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it hugely matters.

You can use `spans`, but you will probably need to set their style to `display: block;` (spans are `display: inline;` by default).

Otherwise, using `div`s is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I personnaly like using `div`s instead of `span` since `div`s old texts and block of contents. In addintion, I have separated html from css in the following code

```
 <div id='container'>
    <div class='left'>1</div>
    <div class='left'>2</div>
    ....
    <div class='right'>n</div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
 </div>
```

An the css

```
.left{float:left}
.right{float:right}
.clear{clear:both}
```

PS: Don't forget to clear left and right floating with `clear:both`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which they both do a similar job the only difference is divs have a display:block and span is display:inline, so either one would be okay but I recommend div :)

Answer (score 0):

If they are just holding text, I would recommend **spans** as I personally only use divs to style the page. While text is used to stile or format text. This helps with visually looking at code and being able to differentiate between text and styling.

..but honestly is it totally up to you.